# How to remove extra white space from website when viewed on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, space

Browser is rendering extra white space on the right side on mobile screens. I tried modifying the following properties without any progress:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

It still does not remove the extra white space. I also don't see any element overflowing from the side of the grid. Any ideas?

Thanks!

[image]

My website: [fanismahmalat.com](https://fanismahmalat.com)

Comment: I checked in Chrome at different window widths - can you be more specific with device/browser and add a screenshot?

Comment: @DriveItLikeYouStoleIt I tried on Samsung mobile in Chrome, and the whitespace appeared!

Comment: @DriveItLikeYouStoleIt I have a OnePlus3T phone and added screenshot of it. After I scroll the whole page, on the footer, it goes back to normal.

Answer (score 6):

It seems to be something odd happening when switching to mobile with the scrollbar leaving the white space.

I added the following into CSS in the Chrome inspector and it fixed the issue:

```
html,body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}
```

I only tested this in Chrome, and again with the inspector, but this may help. I noticed you had `height:1000px` (hardcoded to 1000px). I'm not sure why exactly, but I think you can leave that as such if necessary.

Comment: Well, overflow-x:hidden on html,body fixes the white space problem but it brakes all the scrolling structure..

Comment: My apologies, only tested this in mobile emulator on Chrome. You are correct

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I had the exact same problem and the `overflow-x: hidden;` on `html` and `body` fixed my problem. Regarding the scrolling problem, in my case it is working fine in desktop and mobile.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in the image of the laptop that is exceeding in width.
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlg6R.png

Comment: But it is 100% of the .nutri_image which is 12 columns wide inside the .nutri_container. How is it exceeding it?

Comment: This is not true.

Comment: because you are giving height to the image, the height should be by default only give it 100% width in that size

Comment: @kattyazabache sorry, I didn't understand the last part of what you said :)

Comment: if you set it height it does not respect the default width

Comment: so i should set a width too? how much then?

Comment: the images in mobile mode must adapt by themselves, in that size it must have a width: 100% and a height: initial

Comment: @kattyazabache Changed to that but the problem is still there

Comment: @FanisMahmalat it worked for me changing it in that size and placing !important

Comment: @kattyazabache !important where? on the width and and height of the images? To clarify, image size works with that settings (they take up only the width of the outer div - but the white space though is still there.

Comment: @FanisMahmalat The width in mobile mode of the images must be 100% and the height: initial